# RegEx - Trouble Limiting Capture Groups with Lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I've search these forums but I can't quite find what I need.

I'm having trouble applying lookahead to the following RegEx to limit how many matching groups are returned (e.g.; only 15 matches):

```
^'\d+(,\d+(-\d+)?)*$|'\d+(\d+(-\d+)?)*$
```

I'm not a RegEx expert so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your JS code? The best solution likely is to limit the number of matches in the JS code rather than the regex itself

Comment: Why regex everything...? No one would want to read your code if it looks like that.

Comment: Can you add some text examples about what should match and what should not match?